# How to pass Docker credentials to `docker.login` in Salt?

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I am trying to use this code snippet to login to DockerHub in Salt:

```
docker.login
  module.run:
    - registries:
      - hub
```

How do I pass proper Docker credentials here so that the minion can login to DockerHub? Additionally I'll be using a Docker `token` to log-in since I have two-factor authentication enabled in the DockerHub account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is in [the documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dockermod.html#authentication):

You need to put this data in the minion config, its grains, or its pillar

```yaml
docker-registries:
  hub:
    username: foo
    password: s3cr3t
```

And then a single call will login and cache your token

```sh
salt-call docker.login
```